# AngularJS Module sub dependencies available to sibling modules?

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, meanjs

First, some context for my question, which is also explained in the [MEAN.JS docs](http://meanjs.org/docs.html#angularjs-modules): my angular app `Foo` is bootstrapped from my `init.js` file, which has this line:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['FooCore']);
});
```

My `FooCore` app has several vendor dependencies that I list in the normal manner in its setter which happens just before this line.

Next, the components of my app (search, profile, dashboard, etc) are in their own modules. Every time I declare a sub-component of `FooCore` I add it to its dependencies with:

```
angular.module('FooCore').requires.push('ModuleBar');
```

So, logically, all of my app's components are able to talk to each other (e.g. share directives), which makes sense to me. My question is this: say `ModuleBar` has a vendor dependency X that only it needs - so I declare that dependency in `ModuleBar`'s setter - why is X available to all the sibling components of my `FooCore` app? Here's a visual representation:

```
FooCore
|----ModuleBar => angular.module('ModuleBar', ['vendor-X']);
|    |---- vendor-X
|
|----ModuleBaz => angular.module('ModuleBaz', []);
```

Shouldn't `vendor-X` only be available to `ModuleBar`? Why am I finding it is available to `ModuleBaz` as well?

Comment: Looks like someone else has had similar thoughts: http://michalostruszka.pl/blog/2015/05/21/angular-dependencies-naming-clash/